# Is there a way to fetch data inside RemoteViewService from Room Database?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

This is the ViewModel:

```
class TaskViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
val allTasks: LiveData<MutableList<Task>>
private val repository: TaskRepository

init {
    val dao = TasksDatabase.getInstance(application).getNotesDao()
    repository = TaskRepository(dao)
    allTasks = repository.allNotes
}

fun addNote(note: Task) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.insert(note)
}

fun updateNote(note: Task) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.update(note)
}

fun deleteNote(note: Task) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.delete(note)
}

fun deleteAllNote() = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.deleteAllNotes()
}
}


class TasksWidgetService() : RemoteViewsService() {
lateinit var alltasksLiveData: LiveData<MutableList<Task>>
lateinit var viewModel: TaskViewModel
override fun onGetViewFactory(intent: Intent?): RemoteViewsFactory {
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application)
        .create(TaskViewModel::class.java)
    alltasksLiveData = viewModel.allTasks
    return TasksWidgetItemFactory(applicationContext, intent!!)
}
```

This is the taskswidgetitemfactory:

```
inner class TasksWidgetItemFactory(context: Context, intent: Intent) : 
    RemoteViewsFactory {
    private var context: Context
    private var appWidgetId = 0
    private var tasksData: MutableList<Task> = mutableListOf()
    init {
        this.context = context
        this.appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
            AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
        )
        alltasksLiveData.observeForever { tasks ->
            tasksData.clear()
            tasksData.addAll(tasks)
            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
                .notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.widget_stack_view)
        }

    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        //connect to data source
    }

    override fun onDataSetChanged() {

    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        // close the connection
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return tasksData.size
    }

    override fun getViewAt(postion: Int): RemoteViews {
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_item)
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_task_name, tasksData[postion].title)
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_task_date, tasksData[postion].description)
        return views
    }

    override fun getLoadingView(): RemoteViews? {
        return null
    }

    override fun getViewTypeCount(): Int {
        return 1
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

}

}
```

I'm working on an Android widget for a to-do list application, and I'm using a RemoteViewsService to populate my widget's UI elements. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to fetch data from my TaskViewModel (which is part of my app's architecture) and display it within the widget using RemoteViews. How can I achieve this?

I have a TaskViewModel that provides access to a LiveData list of tasks. Each task has a title, description, and priority. My RemoteViewsFactory is responsible for fetching data and returning RemoteViews for my widget's collection-based UI (e.g., a stack view).

Here's an overview of what I have:

- A TaskViewModel in my app's architecture, which provides access to task data through a LiveData list.
- A RemoteViewsService that uses a RemoteViewsFactory to populate UI elements in my widget.
- A widget layout that consists of a ListView or StackView where I want to display the tasks' data.

I'm not sure how to bridge the gap between fetching data from TaskViewModel and displaying it within the widget's UI using RemoteViews. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76988486/how-do-i-make-viewmodels-talk-to-each-other-in-a-compose-desktop-app/76989122?noredirect=1#comment135725070_76989122) about how to have two view models talk to each other. Here it is a view model and a service.

The key idea is that any live data in a view model should only be read by the UI it is associated with. Overall, event input generates new data that should be passed down to the data layer and stored there. Then other parts of your app that need to reference it can also use the same source of truth in the repository.

Note you have tightly coupled your repo to your view model. Your repo should expose observable flows to read data out of it (turned to live data the view model), as well as update functions to write data. But it shouldn’t be tightly coupled.